# How do I insert my image data from array into canvas so that I can download it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm making a web app for drawing pixel art. The app itself works, I can choose canvas size, colors and tools to draw. Now I want to generate an image from it.
My canvas is a grid of divs that change background color when you draw on them. I made a function that creates a 2D array with each item having 4 values (red, green, blue, alpha).
Here's a function I use:

```
function rgb2pngStart(val) {
    let finish = val.length - 1;
    let sliced = val.slice(4, finish)
    let stringAr = sliced.split(', ');
    let R = parseInt(stringAr[0]);
    let G = parseInt(stringAr[1]);
    let B = parseInt(stringAr[2]);
    let pixelArray = [R, G, B, 255];
    return pixelArray;
}

function createArray() {
    let sideInPixels = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--number');
    let canvasX = [];
    let canvasY = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= sideInPixels; i++) {
        for (let j = 1; j <= sideInPixels; j++) {
            let pixel = document.getElementById(i + ' ' + j).style.backgroundColor;
            canvasX[j - 1] = rgb2pngStart(pixel);
        }
        canvasY[i - 1] = canvasX;
    }
    return canvasY; 
}
```

I was trying to create a canvas, using some old answers here, and put my data into imagedata and then show that image to user so that he could download it. But I don't know how do I do that...

So, how do I generate image from this array? Or what should I change for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convenient approach would be to use an actual [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) element: you can [create `ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData) from your RGBA pixel information and [put](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) it to the canvas [context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) — and then generate a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) or a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob), which can be used to create an [object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) (both of which can be used as download targets).